# Javascript RegExp not escaping parenthesis properly. Why?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, parentheses

I had this code that didn't work as I expected. For some reason, it seems that the escaping of the parentheses was not working. This is the original code:

```js
var string = "url('http://localhost/custom/img/image.jpg')"; /* it can be single or double quotes */
var base_url = "http://localhost"; /* this can be any url */
var re = new RegExp("url\((\"|\')" + base_url + "\/(.*)(\"|\')\)"); /* notice the escaped parentheses in two places */
var clean_str = string.replace(re,'$2');
console.log clean_str
```

No match was found so the result in console was: **url('http://localhost/custom/img/image.jpg')**

So I change the RegExp line to the one below:

```js
/* I replaced the escaping character with a character set */
var re = new RegExp("url[(](\"|\')" + base_url + "\/(.*)(\"|\')[)]");
```

result in console: **custom/img/image.jpg**

And now it works. 
What am I doing wrong on the first one? I tried some simpler expressions, with trying to escape parentheses, like

```js
var re = new RegExp("url\(");
```

and got problems like "Unterminated group".

Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape \ within a string: `/\(/` is  `new RegExp("\\(")`. That's why using regexp litterals is much clearer.